# WPF ToolbarControl binding breaks in overflow mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolbar

I'm writing an app that has a series of buttons in a toolbar. The problem I am having is that the `Command={Binding ...}` breaks for the buttons that extend into the overflow flyout of the toolbar control.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AppConfigs, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
        MaxHeight="100"
        MaxWidth="100"
        OverflowMode="AsNeeded">
        <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button
                    Name="btn"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.IconClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Loc}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconLoc}" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Ideally the `IconClickCommand` would be a part of the items in the `ItemTemplate`, but due to other aspects of the code I have to keep it in the ViewModel of the outside view.

I've tried a few things with the `RelativeSource` binding, but to no avail. All of the other bindings on these buttons (tooltip, content image, etc.) still work.

Comment: Yes' the flyout(Popup I guess), is not part of the VisualTree of the toolbar, that's why it cant travel up to find the DataContext.
You really need to make a viewmodel per item(a wrapper of your own maybe).
You can use a converter on the ItemsSource property to return a new list of your own class to wrap the original.

Comment: It's a shame that the `ItemSource` of the `ToolBar` doesn't extend into the overflow. It is the same list, after all. I will try to refactor some things to allow the property to reside in each element of the `ItemSource`.

Comment: Unless someone comes up with an alternate workaround!

Comment: I understand but technically there is a second ItemsControl in the overflow Popup for that to work as it is.

Comment: Actually, upon further review this is not a good solution. There will be n references to the command, but we really only need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Name` property of the `UserControl` and use `x:Reference`:

```
<UserControl ... Name="uc">
...
<ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button
            Name="btn"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.IconClickCommand, Source={x:Reference uc}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Loc}">
```